# sed doesn't match lines that start with '#' if there are blank spaces or tabs before it

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to output all the lines from apache configuration and just trying to show important lines without the comments (lines that start with # or blank lines [$]), to do that I did:

```
sed '/^#\|^$/d' httpd.conf
```

But it still shows some lines if they have a blank space or a tab before that character.

Is there any fix to this? I would like to keep using sed instead of awk or any other tool if possible.

Comment: why should it? you have `^#` which is literally "start of line followed IMMEDIATELY by a hash". There's no allowance for anything else. `[space]#` is not "start of line followed by hash", it's "start of line followed by space followed by hash", and obviously doesn't match the pattern. This isn't a sed problem, it's your regex that's wrong.

Comment: $ like this is end of string.

Comment: @JohnKugelman You are totally right. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[ \t]*` to the regex to optionally match spaces and tabs.

```
sed '/^[ \t]*#\|^[ \t]*$/d' httpd.conf
```

Or, using parentheses to avoid repetition:

```
sed '/^[ \t]*\(#\|$\)/d' httpd.conf
```

Comment: I'm curious since you said that ^$ meant a blank line, why are you including a tab in ^[ \t]*$ ? Isn't that unnecessary?

Comment: @Victor: For added robustness, John's answer also eliminates _all-whitespace_ lines (_blank_ lines), not just _empty_ lines (`^$`).

Answer (score 1):

`sed '/^[[:space:]]*[#$]/d' httpd.conf` works for me.

```
$ cat httpd.conf
TEST1
# test2
# test3
TESTkkk
$ Another comment
     $ Another comment2
     # Another comment
        # Another comment with tab

$ sed '/^[[:space:]]*[#$]/d' httpd.conf
TEST1
TESTkkk
```

That expression says that if the first character, followed by any number of spaces, is one of the chars from the set `#$`, then delete (`d`) that line from output.

Update: `[[:space:]]` worked for me for tabs as well, however the alternative, based on https://superuser.com/a/786423/44976 is:

```
sed '/^[ \t]*[#$]/d' httpd.conf
```

Both these expressions were tested on the following version on OSX :

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted you, but it did work for lines that don't start with space but not for the ones that have either a space or a tab before it.

Comment: This won't remove blank (or all-whitespace) lines, but will remove any that start with a dollar sign. This is because `[#$]` matches `$` as a literal character, rather than as an end-of-line marker.